# Constructor of subclass' prototype is enumerable in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, inheritance

Here is my code:

```
class Animal {
    constructor(public name: string){}
}
class Cat extends Animal {
    constructor(public name: string) {
        super(name);
    }
}
```

It outputs the following code:

```
var __extends = this.__extends || function (d, b) {
    for (var p in b) if (b.hasOwnProperty(p)) d[p] = b[p];
    function __() { this.constructor = d; }
    __.prototype = b.prototype;
    d.prototype = new __();
};
var Animal = (function () {
    function Animal(name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    return Animal;
})();
var Cat = (function (_super) {
    __extends(Cat, _super);
    function Cat(name) {
        _super.call(this, name);
        this.name = name;
    }
    return Cat;
})(Animal);
```

And as you can see from [this demo](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=0&ts=4.6.2#code/MYGwhgzhAECCB2BLAtmE0DeAoavrAHt4IAXAJwFdgSCyAKABwoCMRFhp4xkBTALmikyieAHMAlBgC%20WGaEgwAwmBLQeADxI94AExgIUaTDjyFi5KjXpNW7Tt36DyIicbzvBFBj3pde4gG4TXBkZLAAzWmg6M1JoBmgRTh4Ad2hlEjoAchAAT3h1LPFxN3wiCAIQHgA6EAJRRkDZLCA), the `constructor` gets enumerated as a key.

The property `constructor` of the Class Cat's prototype should be non-enumerable, but the method **__extends** has changed this. How can I repair this?

I know the following code can achieve this, but I want a way that TypeScript natively supports!

```
Object.defineProperty(Cat.prototype, 'constructor', {
    enumerable: false
});
```

Comment: I had a similar issue with the `__extends` function and the TypeScript maintainers' position seems to be to not use ES5 features in it.

However, they do allow you to replace the function by assigning to `__extends` before any sub-classing is done.

Comment: Uh, why do you care about the enumerability of prototype objects anyway?

Comment: @Bergi I ran into this when targeting ES5 and using jQuery's `ajax`. When it serializes objects, it checks if a property is a method, and calls it if it is. This means that if a subclass instance gets serialized, the `constructor` will get called when it shouldn't. __But__ FWIW, you can now target ES2015 and later, and this problem goes away. This ended up giving me enough firepower to get us to drop IE11 support early.

Comment: @GeneralGrievance Really? [`$.param`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/) does not document calling methods. But in general I'd recommend `JSON.stringify`, which will only call `toJSON()` methods and ignore any others.

Comment: @Bergi Yeah, it's a weird thing. Here's a demo: https://jsfiddle.net/jv68qm57/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define your own `__extends` variable that uses `Object.create` instead of `new __()` to setup the prototype chain.

There is a feature request to allow you to do this at a global level: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1622